# How to add webpush to model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, service-worker, web-push

[webpush documentation](https://github.com/zaru/webpush) shows what works in a controller...

```
post "/push" do
  Webpush.payload_send(
    message: params[:message],
    endpoint: params[:subscription][:endpoint],
    p256dh: params[:subscription][:keys][:p256dh],
    auth: params[:subscription][:keys][:auth],
    vapid: {
      subject: "mailto:sender@example.com",
      public_key: ENV['VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY'],
      private_key: ENV['VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY']
    }
  )
end
```

but I'm trying to refactor into a model so that I can start running rake task `challenge.send_web_push(title: 'Here is a title', body: 'Here is a body')`

I'm specifically stuck on how to refactor js code...

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready
.then((serviceWorkerRegistration) => {
  serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
  .then((subscription) => {
    $.post('/push', {
      subscription: subscription.toJSON(),
    });
  });
});
```

so that the `subscription` will be created via `send_web_push`...

```
def send_web_push(title: , body: )
  Webpush.payload_send(
    vapid: {
      subject: "mailto:sender@example.com",
      public_key: "BB1BO99HPVefIunkzz8sZSNhlEKuH62olxDKHx9qsEsjtnIF8DdvE8Yp5rxTOSF-VqY2hdjBxeUqulVs9E2XUXjQ=",
      private_key: "SUvPgPr9PU_YAyvHorM0NcaMbSLEoOzqdyLlN2OgRN2Q="
    },
    message: {
      title: title,                 
      body: body,                  
      icon: "assets/default.png" 
    }.to_json
  )
end
```

Comment: So, are you trying to trigger a Web Push when somebody creates a new record for your model?

Answer (score 0):

You can see on https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/

> Use Firebase a new way to enjoy coding and handling database